# Summer 19 breaks undocumented lightning:inputField feature - variant="label-hidden", what are alternatives?

Tags: lightning-recordeditform, lightning-inputfield

Seems like attribute doesn't work anymore.

I know before label-hidden variant, I used to be able to hide labels using some CSS. Unsure what it was anymore.

Comment: Aura or LWC? Just checking.

Comment: have you reported this to Salesforce? have you checked list of known issues for available workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue with adding this css:

```
.THIS .slds-form-element__label {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Maybe it can help you!

Comment: Sorry but that will hide all labels on screen, not a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote couple of these selectors that if anyone knows how to simplify - definetely let me know. Seems super fragile and ugly at least (dunno why comma separation didn't work here; ultimately I'd like to select any `label` in the hierarchy, not just immediate child).

Here's the CSS:

```
.THIS .inputField-label-hidden > * > label {
    display: none !important;
}
.THIS .inputField-label-hidden > * > * > label {
    display: none !important;
}
.THIS .inputField-label-hidden > * > * > * > label {
    display: none !important;
}
.THIS .inputField-label-hidden > * > * > * > * > label {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Use:

```
                <lightning:inputField
                        class="inputField-label-hidden"
                        fieldName="Something__c"/>
```

Comment: These worked with picklist, datetime, time fields. Haven't tested with others.